# Query MongoDB Array via Pymongo and only return the element that is LIKE a specified value into a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pymongo-3.x

I have a MongoDB database with documents that contain an array called "links" with an element for every web page that was crawled in a previous step. Also included as an ID and the domain for the website.

Here is an example document:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5eabc5085ad3f439d5dc6940"
},
"domain": "http://www.linnlanes.com/",
"links": ["http://www.linnlanes.com/index.html", "http://www.linnlanes.com/ContactUS/contactus.htm", "http://www.linnlanes.com/HoursRates/rates.htm", "http://www.linnlanes.com/Food/Menu.htm", "http://www.linnlanes.com/BowlingSpecials/specials.htm", "http://www.linnlanes.com/BirthdaySpecials/parties.htm", "http://www.linnlanes.com/ProShop/proshop.htm", "http://www.linnlanes.com/Tournaments/tournaments.htm", "http://www.lebanonusbc.org/Leagues/leagues.htm", "http://www.LebanonUSBC.org/", "http://www.linnlanes.com/BowlingSpecials/tacotuesday.htm", "http://www.linnlanes.com/BowlingSpecials/niteowl.htm"]
```

}

I am trying to pull the data into a Python Dataframe via pymongo and pandas. My example code follows:

```
import pymongo
import pandas as pd

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["crawler"]
mycol = mydb["links"]
myquery = {"links": {"$regex": u"contact"}}
df = pd.DataFrame(mycol.find(myquery))
print(df['links'])
```

When I run the above code I get all of the documents that have "contact" in one of their "links" elements. The problem is that it is pulling in every element of "links". I want to only get the element that contained "contact". I'm open to a different method for performing the "like" function, other than regex as shown.

**What I am getting:**

```
0      [http://www.linnlanes.com/index.html, http://w...
Name: links, Length: 414, dtype: object
```

**What I want to get:**

```
0      [http://www.linnlanes.com/ContactUS/contactus.htm]
Name: links, Length: 414, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

I was pretty close, this works:

```
import pymongo
import pandas as pd

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["crawler"]
mycol = mydb["links"]
myquery = {"links": {"$regex": u"contact"}}
df = pd.DataFrame(mycol.find({"links": {"$regex": u"contact"}}, {"links.$": 1}))
print(df['links'])
```